# XMLHttpRequest works in browser but not in Node

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make an API call to GitHub's API.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/search/users?q=mohamed3on");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.response);
    }
}
xhr.send();
```

This code executes and returns a JSON file when run in browser.

> {   "total_count": 1,   "incomplete_results": false,   "items": [
>       {
>         "login": "Mohamed3on",
>         "id": 12295159,
>         "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/12295159?v=3",
>         "gravatar_id": "",
>         "url": "https://api.github.com/users/Mohamed3on",
>         "html_url": "https://github.com/Mohamed3on",
>         "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Mohamed3on/followers",
>         "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Mohamed3on/following{/other_user}",
>         "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Mohamed3on/gists{/gist_id}",
>         "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Mohamed3on/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
>         "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Mohamed3on/subscriptions",
>         "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Mohamed3on/orgs",
>         "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Mohamed3on/repos",
>         "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Mohamed3on/events{/privacy}",
>         "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Mohamed3on/received_events",
>         "type": "User",
>         "site_admin": false,
>         "score": 49.68772
>       }   ] }

However, when I run it locally (Webstorm or Node)

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/search/users?q=mohamed3on");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.response);
    }
}
xhr.send();
```

nothing is output in the console.

Comment: Never ever do synchronous request, it is deprecated and a terrible practice, use the `onreadystatechange` callback

Comment: @charlietfl Ok, I've done that. But it still doesn't produce an output in node.

Comment: Why use `XMLHttpRequest` in node anyway? There are better libraries for making requests

Comment: @charlietfl I'm just doing that to run my code in the console and test it directly (I'm using Webstorm) instead of going to chrome each time to run it. If you have a better suggestion, please tell.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is a browser feature. It is not part of Javascript in general or part of node.js.  There is an XMLHttpRequest library for node.js that will implement it there, but if you are writing native node.js code, there are much, much better ways to make http requests such as the [`request()` library](https://github.com/request/request).

Comment: Seems like a lot of extra work when you could just run it in browser or if you are only wanting to test api output use built in rest client

Answer (score 1):

You should use request module for making http/https requests to servers :

```
var request = require('request-promise');

var aUrl = "https://api.github.com/search/users";

var reqOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: aUrl,
  qs: {
    q: 'rohankanojia'
  },
  headers: {
    'user-agent': 'node.js'
  },
  json: true
};

request(reqOptions)
  .then(function(parsedBody) {
    console.log("Got response : "+JSON.stringify(parsedBody));
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log("request failed : "+err);
  });
```

Moreover, you're not passing user-agent in request header. It works fine on my system :

```
rohan@~/Documents/src : $ node request.js 
Got response : {"total_count":1,"incomplete_results":false,"items":[{"login":"rohanKanojia","id":13834498,"avatar_url":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/13834498?v=3","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/rohanKanojia","html_url":"https://github.com/rohanKanojia","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/rohanKanojia/followers","following_url":"https://api.github.com/users/rohanKanojia/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https://api.github.com/users/rohanKanojia/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/users/rohanKanojia/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.com/users/rohanKanojia/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/users/rohanKanojia/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/rohanKanojia/repos","events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/rohanKanojia/events{/privacy}","received_events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/rohanKanojia/received_events","type":"User","site_admin":false,"score":29.729874}]}
```

for doing the same on client-side:

```
<body>
<script>

function httpGet(theURL) {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open("GET", theURL);
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xmlHttp.send(null);


  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var response = null;
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      response = xmlHttp.responseText;
      document.getElementById("response").value = response;
    }
  };
}

</script>

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="get Data" 
  onclick="httpGet('https://api.github.com/search/users?q=rohankanojia')" />

<br>
Response : <input id="response" type="label"/>
</body>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: The OP appears to be trying to test client-side code in node.js.  Thus rewriting the code to use node.js functions that are not available in the browser is probably not what this question is about.

Comment: Yes @jfriend00. My project mostly deals with the Github API, and I think I can do that on the client-side (interact with the APIs, display results) without needing a back-end, so I'd rather all the code be on the client side.

Comment: Hey, it creates normal http request but it has to be a xmlHttpRequest so that the server can identify the type of request
There has to be certain headers

Answer (score 1):

First off, node.js is not a good test environment for code that is intended to run in a browser and uses anything that's a browser feature and not part of the ECMAScript standard.

XMLHttpRequest is a browser feature. It is not part of Javascript in general or part of node.js. So, trying to run code in node.js that uses XMLHttpRequest simply will not work as that object does not exist.

node.js has `http.get()` (in the http module) that can do HTTP requests, but since that doesn't exist in the browser, if you changed your code to run in node.js, then it wouldn't run in the browser.

There is an `XMLHttpRequest` library for node.js that will implement that object in node.js, but if you are writing native node.js code, there are much, much better ways to make http requests such as the `request()` library.

If you really want to test code that is intended to run in the browser and uses browser-specific features, then you probably should just test that code in the browser itself or use a specific product that is designed to simulate the browser environment for testing.  Otherwise, you may have to make adaptations to get the browser-specific stuff to run in node.js and then you aren't testing the same exact code.

Comment: Should I just use Node from the start?

Comment: @MohamedOun - That depends entirely upon your application.  If you don't need the browser, then yes, use node.